# Meaning of "package selection" in APT?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

According to the `dpkg` man page, a selection state of *install* means "The package is selected for installation". A selection state of *deinstall* means "The package is selected for  deinstallation  (i.e.  we  want  to remove all files, except configuration files)".

What confuses me, and what I would like to clarify: After I remove a package, it is in the selection state *deinstall*. But it's already removed. How can something that is removed be in any state? And I *did* remove all files, I don't "want to remove" them.

Same for the *install* selection state: How can a package be "selected for installation" if it is already installed?

In the same vein, the man page of `dpkg-query` differentiates between *desired action* and *package status*, which I understand to be the same as *selection state* and *state*, respectively. Most packages have a desired action of *Install* and a status of *Installed*. Again, what is this supposed to mean? Why do we desire installing a package that is already installed?

And the big question: Under which circumstances is this distinction between selection/desired state and normal state relevant at all?

Answer (score 1):

"**Package selection state**" tells dpkg what you WANT.

"**Package state**" tells dpkg whether a package is ACTUALLY installed or not.

*How can a package be "selected for installation" if it is already installed?* is a (understandable) misunderstanding of the language. It does not mean *in the future* -- dpkg has no concept of future or past.

In most cases, your preference and the system status will match. That's a good thing. It means that your system is working properly:

```
       Selection State                          State
I want Package X to be installed     --and-- Package X is installed.
I want Package Y to be NOT installed --and-- Package Y is NOT installed.
```

A discrepancy...

```
       Selection State                          State
I want Package X to be NOT installed --but-- Package X is installed
```

...should be investigated. It sometimes indicates problems (conflicting packages, corrupt packages) if the same discrepancy persists. dpkg is not designed to solve discrepancies for you...but apt is.

Comment: I beleive that should be `package status` instead of `selection status`. :) I come from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366789/what-is-package-selection-states-of-debian-packages) and would like to figure out how does these things work under the hood. According to your reply, is `selection state` used to tell apt what I really want and let it accomplish my goals? If I do not need say packageA anymore, is it enough to just `dpkg --set-selections packageA deinstall` and run `apt upgrade` ?

Comment: Edited terms to more closely match `man dpkg`