# What is package selection states of debian packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

If you try to invoke man page of `dpkg`, you will see two states about debian packages like me which are Package states and Package selection states.

As far as I understand based on the man page, it seems that the packages are selected by something which is going to `install`, `hold`, `deinstall` or `purge` each of them.

My question is what is this `something`? How can we benefit from knowing these selection state?

Comment: This question and its answer which I found by searching the site might help you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206747/meaning-of-package-selection-in-apt

Comment: @David Thanks. I left some comments below the only answer. But I am not quite clear even after reading the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are two possible `something` that set dpkg Package Selection States (what you WANT the package system to look like).

   - You
   - Apt
2. The only benefit of knowing Package Selection States is for troubleshooting when `dpkg` does not do what you expect. Most users lose nothing by not needing to manually de-conflict dependencies, since apt is designed to happily do it for them.